# Java REST Web Service 404 error

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jakarta-ee, jersey

I am very new to restful web service. It seems that I did everything fine but I am not sure where is the problem and I am getting this in logs. 
`Sep 30, 2016 3:50:23 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig init
INFO: No provider classes found.
Sep 30, 2016 3:50:23 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.17.1 02/28/2013 12:47 PM'`

 I am trying to access my web service via this URL 
`http://localhost:8080/usermanagment/listuser`

Following are my files: 
**web.xml**

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>listuser</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.manageuser.usermanagement.services</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>listuser</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/listuser/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

**ListUserService.java**

```
@Path("/listuser")
public class ListUserService {
    @GET
    @Produces("text/html")
        public Response listUserRequest() {
        return Response.status(200)
                .entity("No User").build();

    }
}
```

Please guide me. its been 3hours but I am unable to have a clue

Comment: where is your usermanagement in the servlet mappings? I am not sure as i don't use web.xml files, but wouldn't your url be: /listuser/listuser or just /listuser ?

Comment: `usermanagment` is war file name

Comment: "usermanagment" is really the name and not a typo? (missing an *e* there)

Comment: Is the `ListUserService` in this package `com.manageuser.usermanagement.services` or a subpackage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your servlet scanning is mapped to /listuser

your service should be available in `http://localhost:8080/usermanagment/listuser/listuser`